# Is there a way to sign my app so the user doesn't have to check unknown sources?

Tags: android, signing

I am not planning on releasing my app through the market, however I also do not want the user to have to check the unknown sources to be able to install it.  Is there some way of signing it where I can avoid it or another work around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'unknown sources' refers to anything not in the Market. I have never heard of any way to get around it.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of.

"the market" is the only valid "known" source, and everything else seems to need the check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe its possible unless you push them to the phone with ADB.

Comment: Even then, you still need to check "Unknown Sources" don't you?

Comment: Just tried it.  I was able to with the "Unknown Sources" disabled, but USB debugging was still enabled -_-